# flash as3 - bit101 component window background color

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, components

I'm using the bit101 components for flash in as3, and I have a window with a white background color. I want to make that color semi-transparent. If I set the alpha for the window, everything inside the window is also semi-transparent. I just want the background. How do I accomplish this? This is my code:

```
window = new Window(square, 10, 10, 'ADVANCED\t\t\t\t\t\t\t Use spacebar to randomize values');
            window.width = 380;
            window.height = 140;
            window.hasMinimizeButton = true;
            window.shadow = false;
            window.minimized = true;
            window.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onWindowResizeHandler, false, 0, true);
            window.color = 0xFFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at the source code, it appears that the `Window` contains a `Panel`, and the `Panel` contains a protected `_background` object.

https://github.com/minimalcomps/minimalcomps/blob/master/src/com/bit101/components/Panel.as

```
override public function draw():void
{
    super.draw();
    _background.graphics.clear();
    _background.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0, 0.1);
    if(_color == -1)
    {
        _background.graphics.beginFill(Style.PANEL);
    }
    else
    {
        _background.graphics.beginFill(_color);
    }
    _background.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _width, _height);
    _background.graphics.endFill();
    ...
```

I would try to extend both the `Window` and the `Panel` classes and somehow add the ability to specify a `backgroundAlpha` property, which would be the second argument to `beginFill()` above. It looks like a lot of work.

There doesn't appear to be a more straightforward way to do this.